# tomcat not show on run/debug toolbar in intelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

After i config everything related to tomcat in IntelliJ.

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTrTO.png)

the tomcat does not not show.

Can someone help me out?

[not tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUVQQ.jpg)

Comment: click on *edit configurations* and add a tomcat launcher from there

Comment: Yes, use the `+` button to actuall add the run configuration, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: Thank you guys. I figure it out!